# Extract Leaflet map Json info

Tags: leaflet

I want to ask if its possible to download the Json source of a leaflet web map layer, I want to extract the info from a map that returns info on a selected feature, inspecting the element I can see the selected info in Json format, but I want to know; first if it's possible, and, if it cloud be done, some light on how to approach it, I'm a noob in web scraping, thanks

Comment: You mention web scrapping and inspecting elements, does that mean you do not have control of the page you want to extract data from? Your question sounds quite unclear the way it is currently written.

Comment: Yes, I dont have control of the page, I can only get one feature data by clicking on the map, which is a map of a city's parcels, my question is if I can batch-request all the features inside a city and save it as a GeoJSON, dont know how to approach this, and I only want a path of how to get this, I asume is through web scrapping, but I don't know if it's possible, thanks

Comment: Any data that reaches your browser should be scrappable. But it usually requires deeply reverse engineering the webpage. Depending on how the page is coded, it may be easy or very difficult. It is impossible to help you further with so little details.